# Counting number of occurrences on the whole Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

My dataset has this structure

```
A = [A1, A2, A3, A4]
B = [B1, B2, B3]
C = [C1, C2, C3, C4, C5]
```

I want to count the occurrences of all variables in my dataset, such as:

```
A1    3
A2    2
A3    1
...
C4    4
C5    5
```

I have tried

```
df.groupby(df.columns[0]).A.count()
```

but it only works column by column, is there any way to count occurrences for the whole dataset at once?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you show your data , using print(df.head(10))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stack` the `value_counts`

```
df.stack().value_counts()
Out[1298]: 
4    2
3    2
2    2
5    1
1    1
dtype: int64
```

Data input

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4],'B':[2,3,4,5]})
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for, thank you very much

Comment: @ThanhNguyen yw~ happy coding

Answer (score 2):

```
pd.value_counts(df.values.ravel())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` with `count` on `axis = 1`

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4],'B':[2,3,4,5]})
>>> df.apply(pd.value_counts).count(axis=1)
```

Outputs

```
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    1
dtype: int64
```